# How to cast DATETIME as a DATE in mysql?

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

My query is this. I have a bunch of entries and i want to group them by date. But instead of having date in my database, I have a datetime field. What do I do?

```
select * from follow_queue group by follow_date cast follow_date as date
```

That's not working.

Comment: Try: `select * from follow_queue group by cast(follow_date as date)` first.

Comment: you don't need to cast, just use the DATE() function

Comment: Doesn't the DATE() function cast the datetime to a string? Sure, it works for grouping by date, but I think NawaMan's answer is more correct based on the phrasing of the question

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Use [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

```
select * from follow_queue group by DATE(follow_date)
```

Comment: How do I get the "count" for entries per date? Just do select field,count(*) from follow_queue group by date(follow_date)?

Comment: Yup. `select DATE(follow_date), count(*) from follow_queue group by 1`

Comment: Group by 1? What does that mean?

Comment: It means group by first column in the select list, in this case `DATE(follow_date)`. You can do that with `ORDER BY` as well - `ORDER BY 1, 2`, for example