# PHP convert datetime in SQL statements

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

Is it possible to convert datetime from SQL statements ?

Example :

```
SELECT * FROM t_status WHERE Function to Convert(date_added) BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-31'
```

My date time format in table t_status like this :

2013-05-20, 18:00 <-- contains time.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert string to date in MySQL using the [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

The date in your sample (assuming the comma is intentional) can be converted with the format string `'%Y-%m-%d, %H:%i'`:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_added, '%Y-%m-%d, %H:%i') BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-31'
```

Or to ignore the time part, do this:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_added, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE DATE(date_added) BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-31'
```

from the manual - [DATE(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) : Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression expr.

Next time please try searching Stackoverflow first as there are numerous questions about this already  - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+select+date+from+datetime

eg.
[datetime mySQL SELECT only date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032047/datetime-mysql-select-only-date)
[How to select date from datetime column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754411/how-to-select-date-from-datetime-column)
[How to cast DATETIME as a DATE in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468807/how-to-cast-datetime-as-a-date-in-mysql)