# Change datatime to date dd/mm/yy

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to query some data and one of them is a datetime format. I want that is shows `dd/mm/yy` with no time on it directly form the select. Is this possible?

My query is and the join_date is datetime that i need to be changed to short date:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,username,join_date,is_active FROM members",$con) 
or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

This query goes directy in a Json output array. So i want to convert it directy form the query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cast DATETIME as a DATE in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468807/how-to-cast-datetime-as-a-date-in-mysql)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. It's not about simply casting as date, it's about the date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the MySQL [`DATE_FORMAT` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for this:

```
SELECT id, username, DATE_FORMAT(join_date, '%d/%m/%y') AS join_formatted, is_active
FROM members
```

In this example, the column name for the formatted date will be `join_formatted`, and its type will be `VARCHAR`.

The format string returns the date as `dd/mm/yy` as requested, but I'm personally more comfortable when the date includes the full century. To get the full century, use uppercase `Y` in the format string: `%d/%m/%Y`.

Comment: +1. for assigning an alias for the expression, +1 for giving a description of the approach used, +1 for omitting the code that doesn't need to change, and showing just the SQL text required, +1 for giving a SQL statement that can be tested. This is a good answer. (You might also note that the value returned is not a DATE but is a VARCHAR).

Comment: Thanks for the kind feedback @spencer7593! Your suggestion to note the return type is, as usual, spot on. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: @Ed: The answer you provided is the kind of answer that I'm looking for, when I'm searching for an answer on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
"SELECT id, username, DATE_FORMAT(join_date,'%d/%m/%y'), is_active FROM members"
```

Comment: yep it sould be little `y` read more on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

Use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT id, username, DATE_FORMAT(join_date, "%d/%m/%y") AS date FROM members;
```

**%Y    Year, numeric, four digits

%y  Year, numeric (two digits)**

For details about date format [link](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)