# Mysql select where date = now if Y-m-d H:i:s

Tags: mysql, date, select, format

How to `SELECT` rows of a particular day if date format is `Y-m-d H:i:s`?

I.e. I'd like to select rows like:

```
WHERE DATE(datet) = '2013-08-07'
```

but values are: `2013-08-07 11:23:45`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cast DATETIME as a DATE in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468807/how-to-cast-datetime-as-a-date-in-mysql)

Comment: exactly like that: MySQL can convert DATETIME to DATE via the DATE() function

Answer (score 1):

You have the solution yourself:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE DATE(datet) = '2013-08-07'
```

Assuming that `datet` is a `DATETIME` column this is the most efficient way of doing since then MySQL will be able to use a potential index on `datet` to process the `WHERE` clause.

Depending your version of MySQL `WHERE datet LIKE '2013-08-07%'` might do the job by using the index too (since the leftmost part of the pattern is constant). But this is less elegant, I think.

---

EDIT: As a matter of fact, by testing it appears that will work efficiently with `VARCHAR`/`CHAR` columns too. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/1c2da/1 (click on "View Execution Plan" to see how the index was used).

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
 SELECT DATE('2013-08-07 11:23:45');
```

It will return

```
    -> '2013-08-07'
```

You can use

```
WHERE DATE(datet) = DATE('2013-08-07 11:23:45')
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Answer (score 0):

You can do this following query try with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `YOUR TABLE` WHERE DATE(`YOUR FIELD`) = DATE("2013-08-07");
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `YOUR TABLE` WHERE `YOUR FIELD` LIKE "%2013-08-07%";
```