# how to separate date and time from same column sql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a column named DateTime but i want to show only Date from column not the time
here is my query to show Date and Time from table

```
select Feedback.DateTime from ctrData2.Feedback
```

So help me to separate from Date from DateTime column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cast DATETIME as a DATE in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468807/how-to-cast-datetime-as-a-date-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this -

```
select date(Feedback.DateTime) from ctrData2.Feedback;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
select YEAR(Feedback.DateTime)+"-"+MONTH(Feedback.DateTime)+"-"+DAYOFMONTH(Feedback.DateTime) 
from ctrData2.Feedback
```

OR

```
select date_format(Feedback.DateTime, '%Y %m %d') from ctrData2.Feedback
```