# Converting a date and time (String) to a Date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in the database which stored the date as a String. I created a new column and made it a date. Now I need to move the dates from the old table into the new, but I get this error:

```
Warning: #1411 Incorrect datetime value: '2020-05-11 19:31' for function str_to_date
```

Here is the code I used.

```
update TABLE_NAME set dateAddedNew = date(str_to_date(dateAdded, '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Here is the structure.

[image]

How can I convert the dateAdded into the dateAddedNew without keeping the time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cast DATETIME as a DATE in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468807/how-to-cast-datetime-as-a-date-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change format RegExp to this (input datetime format):

`update TABLE_NAME set dateAddedNew = date(str_to_date(dateAdded, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'))`

Answer (score 0):

The datetime type is in the form, yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. Your dateAdded string column is missing the seconds (:ss) part so it doesn't quality as datetime.

Here's what I recommend assuming dateAddedNew is a date (NOT datetime) type:

```
update TABLE_NAME set dateAddedNew = date_format(concat(dateAdded,':00'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Just use the date_format function instead and arrange the parameters correctly in the date format. Instead of %m/%d/%Y, use a correct MySQL date format: %Y-%m-%d.

Comment: I'd also like to add that you should avoid letting your MySQL date column have a default as 0000-00-00. this causes problems with the latest MySQL versions. instead, use 1970-01-01 or at least 1000-01-01. Set it as the default when creating the column.